# I want to connect a Cat6 Ethernet Cable. Is it supported to my motherboard?

Tags: ethernet

I want to connect a Cat6 Ethernet Cable. I'm not sure if it is supported with my motherboard. My motherboard model is Gigabyte H61M-S1. If anyone knows or finds out if its supported please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn’t it? A Cat6 ethernet cable has the same standard RJ45 connector used by Cat5 and other ethernet cables. Look at the [official specs](https://www.gigabyte.com/il/Motherboard/GA-H61M-S1-rev-20/sp#sp) where is clearly says “1 x RJ-45 port”

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's supported. Cat 6 is still an RJ-45 port and is backwards compatible so it will work with any Ethernet port.

The only "limitation" that you have is your LAN chip is a Realtek RTL8111F LAN chip (10/100/1000 Mbit), so it will only run up to 1 Gbps. Cat 6 is rated for up to 10 Gbps.